# Pull master changes into forked branch

Tags: git

I have a main master branch (A). I forked the master (B - Forked from A). Created a branch out of the forked master(B), let's say C.

Now, if changes are made on the main master branch A, I want to be able to pull those changes in C.

What git commands should be used in that case?

Comment: Generally, you say you "forked" a repository, meaning you created a new repository that's a copy of the one you started with. So saying *I forked the master* if "master" refers to a branch in a repo, as it usually does, is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches, but the one I would use is to first rebase B onto A, then rebase C onto B.  That way you maintain a single straight line.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge A:

```
git merge A -m "Bringing changes from A"
```

You could rebase on top of a, forgetting about changes from B:

```
git rebase --onto A B C
```

You could merge into B, then rebase C onto B

```
git checkout B
git merge -m "Merging changes from A" A
git checkout C
git rebase B
```

You could also rebase B anto A then rebase C onto the new B but that will require some additional work:

```
git branch temp B # set temp where B was when we started
git checkout B
git rebase A
git rebase --onto B temp C # rebase C onto the new B
```

It really depends on what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, if changes are made on the main master branch A, I want to be able to pull those changes in C.

First things first: if you want to work with the original repository from, say, a clone of your fork of that repo, you should add the original repo as a remote. For example, if you want to refer to the original repo as "original", you could:

```
git remote add original https://myremotegit.mycompany.com/path_to_original_repo.git
```

And then, if you really just want to pull the changes into your branch, checkout your branch and do a pull:

```
git pull original master
```

But as JoelFan suggests, that's probably not what you really want to do. Normally, you'd do this sort of thing to keep a feature branch in sync with the master branch that's shared with others, because you plan to eventually merge whatever changes you're making in your own branch back to that shared branch. Using `rebase` instead of `pull` helps here, because it makes the changes coming from master appear before your own changes in the history, and that avoids merge conflicts that can be very difficult to resolve.